# wsadmin command gives warning *sys-package-mgr*: can't write cache file

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-8, wsadmin

When I run the jython script using wsadmin command on WAS 8.5 ND it shows me below messages:

```
[wsadmin] *sys-package-mgr*: processing modified jar, '/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java_1.7_64/lib/ibmorbtools.jar'
[wsadmin] *sys-package-mgr*: can't write cache file for '/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java_1.7_64/lib/ibmorbtools.jar'
```

I have provided the 777 permission to the specified directory. How can I remove these messages.

Comment: I believe the cache files are written to PROFILE_HOME/temp or PROFILE_HOME/wstemp, so you might check the permissions of your PROFILE_HOME directory.

Answer (score 1):

This warnings usually look like this:

```
...
*sys-package-mgr*: processing modified jar, '/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: can't write cache file for '/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: can't write index file
```

This are confusing. Source of errors is jython underlying wsadmin. Jython is scanning WebSphere *jars*, trying to create a *pkc* file for an each scanned jar and finally is creating or updating the *package.idx* file. Warnings are raised as user running jython/wsadmin has no proper file permissions.

User running wsadmin must have read and write permission for jython cache folder and all contained files. Default cache folder is **temp/cachedir** within WAS profile. For example my "Deployment manager" named **Dmgr01** has jython cache folder within:

> ${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/profiles/Dgmr01/temp/cachedir

Once one proper rights are given *"can't write cache file for"* and *"can't write index file"* warnings will be gone. And *"processing modified jar"* will be raised whenever jars are updated or temp folder cleaned which is rare event for WAS installation.

Answer (score 0):

If wlst works before and doesn't work now, this error means the temp directory "/tmp/wlstTemporacle/packages" are corrupted.

If you go into "/tmp/wlstTemporacle/packages", you will lots of *.pkc files are duplicated with a "$1" in it's name. In your case, the file "ibmorbtools.pkc" will have a crapy sibling "ibmorbtools$1.pkc" there. This is not correct and it means this directory is corrupted.

The solution is to totally remove directory "/tmp/wlstTemporacle/packages", or even entire "/tmp/wlstTemporacle". And then rerun wlst.sh, you will see a new directory structure is created and all *.pkc are copied over correctly. Your above error message will go away.

Notes: In my case, this is oracle WebLogic 10.x.x.x running on Linux. Its WLST is Jython apps. The temp dir for java is point to "/tmp/wlstTemporacle". If your case is different, the easiest way to determine where is temp directory for your environment is to do a full search for file "ibmorbtools.pkc". It's name come from your error message which is "ibmorbtools.jar", just postfix are different.

Hopefully, this will help!

Yubo